# How to know which part of query is executed

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose i have a query

```
create table friends (
userid int,
friend int,
status int 
);
```

Is it posible to know which part of query is being executed?
for example, following example should tell 1 if `(userid=1 and friend=2)` is satisfied or tell 2 if `(friend=2 and userid=1 )` part is executed.

```
//wrong example
select status,@var 
  from friends 
 where @var:=(userid=1 and friend=2) 
    or @var:=(friend=2 and userid=1 );
```

Comment: how about you do 2 separate queries for each 'if' statement?

Comment: I think you want `CASE`

Comment: Suggestion, step away from your code.  In reasonably clear English, state what you are trying to accomplish.  If this explanation involves input paramaters, specify how they are sent, without using any coding terms.

Comment: Thanks Dan, but this is not my original code, This is my sandbox code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT status,
    CASE 
    WHEN (userid=1 and friend=2) THEN 'opt1'
    WHEN (friend=2 and userid=1) THEN 'opt2'
END AS 'var'
FROM friends 
WHERE userid IN (1, 2) 
    OR friend IN (1, 2)
```

Comment: Typo alert! I think you have a transposition in the WHEN's.

Comment: This partially solves the problem, this is executing for every row in table. Can this be effective on only one solution row?

Comment: With a where clause, probably.

Comment: Just add your criteria on the WHERE CLAUSE.

Comment: That completely solves it. Thanks. Please update your solution for other followers to this post. Thanks.